# My Eevee evolved into a Flareon not a Jolteon, despite being nicknamed Sparky. Why?

Tags: pokemon-go

I used Sparky as a name for Eevee so that it would evolve into a Jolteon, but it turned into a Flareon, instead. Why did this happen?

Comment: Have you used this trick already?

Answer (score 1):

This trick only works ***once*** for each name (Pyro, Sparky, Rainer, Tamao, and Sakura). After that, you will not be able to guarantee that eeveelution.

If you named an Eevee "Sparky" previously, it should've evolved into a Jolteon. However, doing it a second time will cause your Eevee to evolve randomly into one of its available eeveelutions (Umbreon and Espeon appear to require an Eevee to have walked a certain amount of distance with you as a buddy to be in the evolution pool).

If you haven't already used this trick, but you still didn't get your desired eeveelution, then make sure you spelled the name correctly, otherwise it definitely won't work.